# Owl Carousel in IE11 doesn't work

Tags: internet-explorer-11, owl-carousel

Owl Carousel works on every browser except anything below IE11.  It even works on IE Edge.  Any help is truly appreciated.

The site is [HERE](http://www.toolekinney.com).

Comment: For anyone who is curious, I fixed it by downloading the files rather than using the CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is curious, I fixed it by downloading the files rather than using the CDN.

Comment: Any luck getting it to work for me, it is not working sir. I downloaded locally

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else interested, if you remove the 'navigation' arrows, it should start working with the dreaded IE11